# Why is the html select background-color black in Chrome when set to transparent?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have the following drop down menu and the background looks black in Chrome but white on Firefox/IE/Safari across Windows/Linux/Mac.  I'm using the latest versions of all those browsers.

```
<style>
select {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png);
}
</style>
<select>
    <option>Serverfault</option>
    <option>Stackoverflow</option>
    <option>Superuser</option>
</select>
```

Does anyone know how I can style the above so that Chrome shows the background as white when the color is set to transparent like in the other browsers?

**EDIT:**
My goal is to display an image in the background of select.  The image shows up properly in every browser except Chrome.

Comment: Stylizing complex components (like select, etc etc) is always going to be complicated because standard html and css really cannot express such templating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2756) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=664), it is a **bug** in Chrome that is supposed to be fixed.

The bug appears in version 2.0. I just tested it in 3.0-beta, and it's fixed.

Comment: I was searching for that bug too, 664 is related to my issue.  I also just installed Chrome dev for mac and linux, they are at 4.0 and have that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using background-color: transparent; for "select"? If you remove that chrome works.

What is the effect you are after? Maybe some demo?

Comment: he probably has a background image behind the "select".

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806434/964227 that I found in another question just like this worked perfectly for me.

Apparently Chrome doesn't accept an image as a select background. So, in order for the color to work, you have to remove the image and then set the color. I'll just copy and paste the other answer here.

```
select {
    background-image: none; /* remove the value that chrome dose not use */
    background-color: #333; /* set the value it does */
    border-radius: 4px;     /* make it look kinda like the background image */
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
```