# White background in select box when viewing in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, google-chrome

this html only in chrome makes the selected value non visible, the bacground of the select in other browsers is colored, only in chrome it's white

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <title>
        title
    </title>    
    <link id="siteThemeLink" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />          
</head>

<body>
<select class='ui-state-error'>
    <option>hi</option>
    <option>hi</option>
    <option>hi</option>
</select>
</body>
</HTML>
```

anybody knows a fix ?

Comment: Its working fine for me (mac - chrome)

Comment: @amosrivera I'm on Windows 7 x64

Answer (score -5, accepted):

With jQuery you can do this

```
$('#selectbox').css({
    'background': 'blue'
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/B2NFE/2/

Comment: @Hussein, is possible to do, if(chrome) all that stuff ^

Comment: Why in godsname would you use javascript (worse even, an entire javascript library) to fix a minor css problem? If you have a flat tire, do you buy a monster truck to carry your car around 'so that it can still drive' or just fix the flat tire?

Comment: @Stephan Muller, because I already use it, I use it a lot to substitute the absence of css inheritance

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question. Still, these are stylesheet properties, you can modify them with CSS.

Comment: @Omu Here's the same example with `if(chrome)`. Now Only chrome will be affected http://jsfiddle.net/B2NFE/5/

Comment: Just tested the example and it does not work in chrome! The background-color is white when you click on the drop-down. This means you cannot select an option without guesswork. Please can we have this unaccepted as an answer!

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome doesn't support a background image on a select, which is why the rule in the stylesheet breaks.

To fix it you will need to specifiy the background color and background image separately, so that browsers that don't support the background image will not ignore the entire rule but will at least pick up the rules they do support:

```
.ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {
  background-color: #E69700;
  background-image: url(images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_20_e69700_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat;
}
```

Alternately, you could just set the background color in the style attribute, but this is not as clean as the other solution:

```
<select class='ui-state-error' style='background-color: #E69700;'>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little old but I ran onto it when looking for the the same anwser and the is a Css way to fix this

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { // target only -webkit browsers

```
select {
    background-image: none; /* remove the value that chrome dose not use */
    background-color: #333; /* set the value it does */
    border-radius: 4px;     /* make it look kinda like the background image */
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

}

Hope that it helps

Comment: Currently the Chrome browser needs this fix to have dropdown select background color applied it seems. I am using "Version 24.0.1312.57 m".  Searched alot before finding this answer. Thanks @webLacky3rdClass! :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to detect the browser to fix the issue:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
$.browser = {
    version: (userAgent.match( /.+(?:rv|it|ra|ie|me)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/ ) || [])[1],
    chrome: /chrome/.test( userAgent ),
    safari: /webkit/.test( userAgent ) && !/chrome/.test( userAgent ),
    opera: /opera/.test( userAgent ),
    msie: /msie/.test( userAgent ) && !/opera/.test( userAgent ),
    mozilla: /mozilla/.test( userAgent ) && !/(compatible|webkit)/.test( userAgent )
};
```

Then change the font color to black:

```
$.each($.browser, function(i, val) {
if($.browser.chrome){
$(o).css({'color':'black'});
}
});
```