# CSS for Dropdown does not works fine in Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I code a style for a HTML dropdown element, it works excellent on FF and Safari but does not on Chrome and IE.

Here i attached image and style code:

[image]

```
.select_box {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(images/input_smal.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 33px;
    padding: 6px 15px 5px;
    width: 292px;
}
```

HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Muhammad Sajid</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15">
        <tr>
            <td nowrap="nowrap">Status</td>
            <td><select class="select_box" id="status" name="status">
                    <option >Open</option>
                    <option >Pending</option>
                    <option >In Progress</option>
                    <option  selected="selected">Closed</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sure the problem arising due to:
**background-color and or background-image** properties but I could not fix them....!

Comment: please push your HTML code also

Comment: Okay I paste HTML code as well

Comment: wated bytes could be written like so : `background: transparent url(images/input_smal.png) no-repeat 0 0;` i dont know if it solves your problem but i usually leave the color out when using a background image `background: url(images/input_smal.png) no-repeat 0 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem in Google Chrome has to do with a bug in version 2.0, but it's solved in 3.0. Here you have a topic about this with link to the bugs:

[Why is the html select background-color black in Chrome when set to transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381175/why-is-the-html-select-background-color-black-in-chrome-when-set-to-transparent)

About IE, are you using IE 7 or lower? If so, `transparent` background is not supported in them. You should apply the same background color than the parent specifically to IE7 and lower (for example with a hack).

Comment: I am using Chrome: 16.0.912.75 m