# Black bars appearing in select box in tablet view

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown in my webpage and its working absolutely fine in browser. When i check in chrome simulator or actual device i get black bars inside. 
Even then the functionality is working. Its some render issue in mobile or tablet view. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

```
 <select >
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: Simple select box. Check edit

Comment: I just checked few different websites in chrome mobile/tablet emulator and i am getting these black bars in most of them. Is this the default behaviour or what?

Comment: My desktop browser & my phone browser working fine but not working properly in chrome emulator, I think this is chrome emulator issues.

Comment: You can look into this article for the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381175/why-is-the-html-select-background-color-black-in-chrome-when-set-to-transparent

Comment: This is a chrome emulator issue, I noticed it lately too - as long as all fine in the target device then I just ignore it

Comment: Thanks...seems like emulator issue only

Comment: You can look into this - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/Q4Rt6d0C4Qo/iQQ68OVqAwAJ

Answer (score 0):

its showed just in emulator or in all browser

if it showed in all browser that because  some css transation or javascript codes in page do this .

try to remove css and javascript one by one and test the page

if its just in emulator you have no problem with your page and its from emualtor , you can use some plugins in chrome or firefox responsive site tools to try your page on diffrent size